# Why is BeautifulSoup4 missing the first file URL?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to catalog the files on this website as a personal exercise. When I run the following code I don't know why I'm not getting the first file url on this website. Any help is appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import regex

url = 'https://www.liberliber.it/online/autori/autori-p/niccolo-paganini/24-capricci-per-violino-solo-op-1/'
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

files = soup.find_all(href=regex.compile("\.mp3$"))

for h in files:
    a = h.findNext('a')
    #print(a.string)
    urls.append(a.attrs['href'])
    tags.append(a.string)
```

files ends up offset by one mp3 file. Why am I not getting the first file and adding another file at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you want `findNext` because you have all of the `a` tags inside of `files`. So perhaps you just want

```
for h in files:
    urls.append(h.attrs['href'])
    tags.append(h.string)
```

Comment: My pleasure. I get a lot of help on this site myself.